# Php ssh2_auth_password authentication failed

Tags: php, ssh

My php script generates an excel file, and I'd like this file to be transfered on our files server, which is different from the web one.

I'm using the ssh2_auth_password() function, but I'm stuck with the `Warning: ssh2_auth_password() [function.ssh2-auth-password]: Authentication failed for root using password` message.

Most of time, this issue is fixed by changing the line `PasswordAuthentication yes` on the sshd_config file. This is done and confirmed by the function `ssh2_auth_none()` which returns an array containing : "0: publickey, 1: password, 2: keyboard-interactive"

When I execute the operation by putty (typing `scp /srv/www/htdocs/**** root@192.168.168.1:/***/***`), and giving the password, it works.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You can enable verbose mode logging on server side and check that log

Comment: Take a look at /var/log/auth.log - What's it showing?

Comment: Well, i checked the log and I could see this : `sshd[23069]: Failed none for invalid user none from 192.168.168.3 port 33501 ssh2`. Then I removed the `ssh2_auth_none()` function, and the authentication is now working. I still have an error but it seems to be with the paths, I'll handle it... Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Explain what you did in an answer and accept it.  That will help the next person who encounters your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I just had to remove the `ssh2_auth_none()`, and it works !